# compile ejb 2.0 in weblogic 10.3

Tags: maven, ant, weblogic, ejb-2.x

How can i compile an ejb 2.0, created with weblogic 8.1 with weblogic 10.3 ?

in weblogic 8.1 i think was used weblogic.ejbc.

I prefer to use ant or maven.

Thanks 
Regards

Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks,

but i've resolved this issue with ant in this manner:

i've declared a weblogic ant task:

```
  <taskdef name="weblogicAppc" classpathref="custom.classpath" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc"/>
```

then i used this task to convert my jar in an ejb compliant jar:

```
<target name="conert-jar-to-ejb" depends="create-ejb-jar">
    <weblogicAppc source="${build.dir}/jar.jar" keepgenerated="true"
    verbose="true" output="${build.dir}/ejb.jar" clientJarOutputDir="." />
</target>
```

thanks,

regards

Answer (score 0):

That should be `weblogic.appc` for WLS 10

see the javadocs at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/ejb/appc_ejbc.html